# JPanel not showing up dynamically inside JLayeredPane

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jlayeredpane

I am building a chess program in Java. I am not able to display a jPanel containing the promotion options, on top of the jPanel, i.e. the Board.

The board is inside a JLayeredPane and when a pawn reaches the final square, I instantiate the PromotionOptions panel inside the event handler and revalidate. But the jPanel is not being displayed.

I already tried setting proper Size & Location to the jPanel object, putting revalidate(), also used repaint() method. I also assigned JLayeredPane a layout of null explicitly.

All of the questions already in stackoverflow related to this, was solved by properly setting the layout, which doesn't appear to be the problem here...

```
// JLayeredPane created here...
class Game extends JFrame {

    Game() {
        super.setLayout(new TableLayout(new double[][]{{0.5, 475, 0.5}, {0.5, 475, 0.5}}));

        JLayeredPane layeredContainer = new JLayeredPane();
        layeredContainer.setLayout(null);

        Board board = new Board(layeredContainer);
        board.arrange();

        layeredContainer.add(board, 1);
        board.setSize(475, 475);

        super.add(layeredContainer, "1, 1");

        super.setSize(600, 600);
        super.setResizable(false);
        super.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);


        super.validate();
    }
}
```

// PromotionOptions created here...

```
public class Board extends JPanel {
//skipping some irrelevant code...
private class PromotionOptions extends JPanel {

    private PromotionOptions(PieceColor color) {
        super.setSize(50,200);
        super.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        super.setLayout(new GridLayout(4, 1));

        ImageIcon queenIcon = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/pieceIcons/" + color.abbr + "Q.png"));
        ImageIcon rookIcon = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/pieceIcons/" + color.abbr + "R.png"));
        ImageIcon bishopIcon = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/pieceIcons/" + color.abbr + "B.png"));
        ImageIcon knightIcon = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/pieceIcons/" + color.abbr + "N.png"));

        JLabel queenLabel = new JLabel(queenIcon);
        JLabel rookLabel = new JLabel(rookIcon);
        JLabel bishopLabel = new JLabel(bishopIcon);
        JLabel knightLabel = new JLabel(knightIcon);

        super.add(queenLabel);
        super.add(rookLabel);
        super.add(bishopLabel);
        super.add(knightLabel);
    }
}
// skipping some more irrelevant code...
private void executeMove(Tile clickedTile) {
// skip to where I create the PromotionOption object and add to layeredPane...
case PROMOTION:
                    moveMade.initialTile.removePiece();
                    JPanel promotionOptions = new PromotionOptions(colorToMove);
                    promotionOptions.setLocation(200,200);
                    layeredPaneContainer.add(promotionOptions, 2);
                    layeredPaneContainer.revalidate();
                    break;
// Some more code here
}
// End of Board class...
}
```

Due to some bug, whenever the pawn reaches the final tile, nothing is displayed and the application continues as it is.

Comment: Cross posted: https://coderanch.com/t/708639/java/JPanel-showing-dynamically-JLayeredPane

Answer (score 0):

After hours of frustrated debugging, I finally somehow made it work correctly. What I did was I added SwingUtilities.invokeLater() method and passed the code inside it like this..

```
case PROMOTION:
                    moveMade.initialTile.removePiece();
                    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
                        JPanel promotionOptions = new PromotionOptions(colorToMove.opposite);
                        promotionOptions.setLocation(clickedTile.getLocation());
                        layeredPaneContainer.add(promotionOptions, 2);
                        layeredPaneContainer.revalidate();
                    });
                    break;
```